# ASP.NET Identity - Modify default connection string name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using EF6 and Identity, and configuring 2 separate connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=db_entity;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=db_identity;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

It works fine, my entities are stored in `db_entity`, and user information (just 5 default aspnet identity tables) are stored in `db_identity`.
[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U17CK.png)

I can see that AspNet Identity is using `DefaultConnection`, and I want to modify that name. I tried to create this custom class (I've not use any custom class for identity before):

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
        public IdentityContext() : base("IdentityContext")
        {

        }

        public static IdentityContext Create()
        {
            return new IdentityContext();
        }
}
```

And change `DefaultConnection` in *web.config* to `IdentityContext`.
But it doesn't work, when I run app, it throws an exception:

*SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\thang\Documents\GitHub\GSSPHN\EmptyWeb\App_Data\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection'.*

It's still looking for `DefaultConnection` that I've changed to `IdentityContext`. How can I modify that connection name?

**SOLVED**: I modified that custom class:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
        public IdentityContext() : base("IdentityContext")
        {
            UserManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(this));
            RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(this));
        }

        public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; set; }
        public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can access `UserManager` and `RoleManager` from `IdentityContext` that pointing to my specified connection name.

Comment: Did you create the project using the Identity template? If so, there's already an `ApplicationDbContext` or something like that in the `Models` folder

Comment: No, I didnt, that's my problem, I'd like to manually setup the project from empty, so there is no `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: You need to register `IdentityContext` in OWIN and use that instead of `IdentityDbContext` then. I'd suggest you to start a new project with the template so that you can see how it's done

Comment: I got it, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change `Startup.Auth.cs` or somewhere that initialized the `UserManager`;

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>());
```

to

```
UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new IdentityContext());
```